# CentOS https error upon starting apache

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, httpd

I am getting an error in CentOS when trying to start/restart apache(httpd):

```
[root@database ~]# /etc/init.d/httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using ctrl.lesamportfolio.com for ServerName                                                  [FAILED]
```

What is the problem?

**Update:**

```
[root@database ~]# cat /var/log/httpd/error_log
[Sun Dec 08 04:26:02 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Dec 08 04:26:02 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Dec 08 04:26:02 2013] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Sun Dec 08 04:26:02 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.3 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Dec 08 08:57:27 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/favicon.ico
[Sun Dec 08 08:57:27 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/favicon.ico
[Sun Dec 08 15:03:48 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/favicon.ico
[Sun Dec 08 15:03:50 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/favicon.ico
[Sun Dec 08 16:36:01 2013] [error] [client 183.136.216.83] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/manager
[Sun Dec 08 18:10:12 2013] [error] [client 68.111.112.192] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/favicon.ico
[Sun Dec 08 22:44:28 2013] [error] [client 220.164.192.28] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php
[Sun Dec 08 22:44:29 2013] [error] [client 220.164.192.28] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php5
[Sun Dec 08 22:44:29 2013] [error] [client 220.164.192.28] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php-cgi
[Sun Dec 08 22:44:30 2013] [error] [client 220.164.192.28] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php.cgi
[Sun Dec 08 22:44:31 2013] [error] [client 220.164.192.28] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php4
[Mon Dec 09 01:16:21 2013] [error] [client 203.171.229.184] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/w00tw00t.at.blackhats.romanian.anti-sec:)
[Mon Dec 09 01:16:21 2013] [error] [client 203.171.229.184] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/phpMyAdmin
[Mon Dec 09 01:16:22 2013] [error] [client 203.171.229.184] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/phpmyadmin
[Mon Dec 09 01:16:22 2013] [error] [client 203.171.229.184] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/pma
[Mon Dec 09 01:16:22 2013] [error] [client 203.171.229.184] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/myadmin
[Mon Dec 09 01:16:23 2013] [error] [client 203.171.229.184] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/MyAdmin
[Mon Dec 09 02:57:40 2013] [error] [client 63.147.126.183] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/robots.txt
[Mon Dec 09 04:20:55 2013] [error] [client 68.111.112.192] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/favicon.ico
[Mon Dec 09 04:24:10 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Dec 09 04:24:11 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Dec 09 04:24:11 2013] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Mon Dec 09 04:24:11 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Dec 09 04:24:11 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Dec 09 04:24:11 2013] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Mon Dec 09 04:24:11 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 09 11:01:58 2013] [error] [client 82.166.118.134] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/favicon.ico
[Mon Dec 09 11:02:03 2013] [error] [client 82.166.118.134] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/etc/styles/zpanelx/css/style.css, referer: http://ctrl.lesamportfolio.com/
[Mon Dec 09 11:22:36 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/etc/styles/zpanelx/css/style.css, referer: http://ctrl.lesamportfolio.com/?module=mailboxes
[Mon Dec 09 11:23:27 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/etc/styles/zpanelx/css/style.css, referer: http://ctrl.lesamportfolio.com/?loggedout
[Mon Dec 09 11:23:36 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/etc/styles/zpanelx/css/style.css, referer: http://ctrl.lesamportfolio.com/
[Mon Dec 09 15:05:03 2013] [error] [client 209.54.112.128] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php
[Mon Dec 09 15:05:03 2013] [error] [client 209.54.112.128] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php
[Mon Dec 09 16:17:59 2013] [error] [client 190.14.242.148] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php
[Mon Dec 09 16:17:59 2013] [error] [client 190.14.242.148] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php5
[Mon Dec 09 16:18:00 2013] [error] [client 190.14.242.148] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php-cgi
[Mon Dec 09 16:18:00 2013] [error] [client 190.14.242.148] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php.cgi
[Mon Dec 09 16:18:01 2013] [error] [client 190.14.242.148] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php4
[Tue Dec 10 01:22:28 2013] [error] [client 91.121.155.85] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php
[Tue Dec 10 05:55:43 2013] [error] [client 101.71.21.1] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php
[Tue Dec 10 05:55:45 2013] [error] [client 101.71.21.1] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php5
[Tue Dec 10 05:55:46 2013] [error] [client 101.71.21.1] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php-cgi
[Tue Dec 10 05:55:47 2013] [error] [client 101.71.21.1] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php.cgi
[Tue Dec 10 05:55:48 2013] [error] [client 101.71.21.1] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php4
[Tue Dec 10 16:12:55 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Dec 10 16:12:56 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Dec 10 16:12:56 2013] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Tue Dec 10 16:12:56 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Dec 10 16:12:56 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Dec 10 16:12:56 2013] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Tue Dec 10 16:12:56 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 10 23:19:16 2013] [error] [client 94.136.45.8] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php
[Wed Dec 11 06:03:03 2013] [error] [client 203.171.229.184] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/w00tw00t.at.blackhats.romanian.anti-sec:)
[Wed Dec 11 06:03:04 2013] [error] [client 203.171.229.184] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/phpMyAdmin
[Wed Dec 11 06:03:05 2013] [error] [client 203.171.229.184] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/phpmyadmin
[Wed Dec 11 06:03:07 2013] [error] [client 203.171.229.184] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/pma
[Wed Dec 11 06:03:09 2013] [error] [client 203.171.229.184] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/myadmin
[Wed Dec 11 06:03:09 2013] [error] [client 203.171.229.184] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/MyAdmin
[Wed Dec 11 06:40:52 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/favicon.ico
[Wed Dec 11 06:40:53 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/favicon.ico
[Wed Dec 11 13:28:51 2013] [error] [client 221.208.168.183] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/manager
[Thu Dec 12 17:49:11 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /etc/zpanel/panel/etc/tmp/storage/zpanelx/a5c2171c96b2c7674efdecc2c9599046.cache:67) in /etc/zpanel/panel/index.php on line 21, referer: http://ctrl.lesamportfolio.com/?module=mailboxes&action=AddMailbox
[Thu Dec 12 21:30:54 2013] [error] [client 85.236.48.92] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php
[Fri Dec 13 06:32:20 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /etc/zpanel/panel/etc/tmp/storage/zpanelx/a5c2171c96b2c7674efdecc2c9599046.cache:67) in /etc/zpanel/panel/index.php on line 21, referer: http://ctrl.lesamportfolio.com/?module=mailboxes&action=AddMailbox
[Fri Dec 13 06:59:41 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /etc/zpanel/panel/etc/tmp/storage/zpanelx/61bb6a738b3924751f38268a1caa13ad.cache:67) in /etc/zpanel/panel/index.php on line 21, referer: http://ctrl.lesamportfolio.com/?module=webmail
[Fri Dec 13 06:59:44 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /etc/zpanel/panel/etc/tmp/storage/zpanelx/eaf9c6bb22809bae8726e6db58b8db6b.cache:67) in /etc/zpanel/panel/index.php on line 21, referer: http://ctrl.lesamportfolio.com/?module=moduleadmin
[Fri Dec 13 06:59:54 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: zpcsfr in /etc/zpanel/panel/dryden/runtime/csfr.class.php on line 44, referer: http://ctrl.lesamportfolio.com/?module=apache_admin
[Fri Dec 13 06:59:55 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/favicon.ico
[Fri Dec 13 06:59:55 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/favicon.ico
[Fri Dec 13 15:43:21 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/etc/styles/zpanelx/css/style.css, referer: http://api.pingrglobe.com/
[Fri Dec 13 15:51:16 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/etc/styles/zpanelx/css/style.css, referer: http://api.pingrglobe.com/?mode=getServers&apiCode=cb8844
job 36 at 2013-12-13 15:53
job 37 at 2013-12-13 15:53
[Fri Dec 13 15:53:10 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] PHP Warning:  chmod(): Operation not permitted in /etc/zpanel/panel/modules/webalizer_stats/hooks/OnDaemonHour.hook.php on line 34, referer: http://ctrl.lesamportfolio.com/modules/zpanelconfig/code/rundaemon.php
Error: Unable to open file usage_201312.html!
Error: Unable to open file index.html!
Error: Unable to open file index.html!
[Fri Dec 13 15:53:10 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] PHP Warning:  chmod(): Operation not permitted in /etc/zpanel/panel/modules/webalizer_stats/hooks/OnDaemonHour.hook.php on line 34, referer: http://ctrl.lesamportfolio.com/modules/zpanelconfig/code/rundaemon.php
Error: Unable to open file usage_201312.html!
Error: Unable to write history file webalizer.hist.new
Error: Unable to open file index.html!
Error: Unable to open file index.html!
[Fri Dec 13 15:53:10 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] PHP Warning:  chmod(): Operation not permitted in /etc/zpanel/panel/modules/webalizer_stats/hooks/OnDaemonHour.hook.php on line 34, referer: http://ctrl.lesamportfolio.com/modules/zpanelconfig/code/rundaemon.php
Error: Unable to open file usage_201312.html!
Error: Unable to write history file webalizer.hist.new
Error: Unable to open file index.html!
Error: Unable to open file index.html!
[Fri Dec 13 15:53:10 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] PHP Warning:  chmod(): Operation not permitted in /etc/zpanel/panel/modules/webalizer_stats/hooks/OnDaemonHour.hook.php on line 34, referer: http://ctrl.lesamportfolio.com/modules/zpanelconfig/code/rundaemon.php
Error: Unable to open file usage_201312.html!
Error: Unable to write history file webalizer.hist.new
Error: Unable to open file index.html!
Error: Unable to open file index.html!
[Fri Dec 13 15:53:10 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] PHP Warning:  chmod(): Operation not permitted in /etc/zpanel/panel/modules/webalizer_stats/hooks/OnDaemonHour.hook.php on line 34, referer: http://ctrl.lesamportfolio.com/modules/zpanelconfig/code/rundaemon.php
Error: Unable to open file usage_201312.html!
Error: Unable to write history file webalizer.hist.new
Error: Unable to open file index.html!
Error: Unable to open file index.html!
[Fri Dec 13 15:53:10 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] PHP Warning:  chmod(): Operation not permitted in /etc/zpanel/panel/modules/webalizer_stats/hooks/OnDaemonHour.hook.php on line 34, referer: http://ctrl.lesamportfolio.com/modules/zpanelconfig/code/rundaemon.php
Error: Can't open log file 
[Fri Dec 13 15:53:48 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/etc/styles/zpanelx/css/style.css, referer: http://api.pingrglobe.com/?mode=getServers&apiCode=cb8844
[Fri Dec 13 15:53:53 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/etc/styles/zpanelx/css/style.css, referer: http://api.pingrglobe.com/?mode=getServers&apiCode=cb8844
[Fri Dec 13 15:55:31 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Dec 13 15:57:24 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 15:57:24 2013] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Fri Dec 13 15:57:24 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Dec 13 15:57:24 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Dec 13 15:57:24 2013] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Fri Dec 13 15:57:24 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 13 15:59:00 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/etc/styles/zpanelx/css/style.css, referer: http://api.pingrglobe.com/?mode=getServers&apiCode=cb8844
[Fri Dec 13 15:59:03 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/etc/styles/zpanelx/css/style.css, referer: http://api.pingrglobe.com/?mode=getServers&apiCode=cb8844
[Fri Dec 13 16:02:01 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/etc/styles/zpanelx/css/style.css, referer: http://api.pingrglobe.com/?mode=getServers&apiCode=cb8844
[Fri Dec 13 16:02:05 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/etc/styles/zpanelx/css/style.css, referer: http://api.pingrglobe.com/?mode=getServers&apiCode=cb8844
[Fri Dec 13 16:02:09 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/etc/styles/zpanelx/css/style.css, referer: http://api.pingrglobe.com/?mode=getServers&apiCode=cb8844
[Fri Dec 13 16:02:13 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/etc/styles/zpanelx/css/style.css, referer: http://api.pingrglobe.com/index.php?mode=getServers&apiCode=cb8844
[Fri Dec 13 16:02:19 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/index.html
[Fri Dec 13 16:02:20 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/favicon.ico
[Fri Dec 13 16:02:20 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/favicon.ico
[Fri Dec 13 16:02:23 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/etc/styles/zpanelx/css/style.css, referer: http://api.pingrglobe.com/?mode=getServers&apiCode=cb8844
[Fri Dec 13 16:02:38 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/etc/styles/zpanelx/css/style.css, referer: http://api.pingrglobe.com/
[Fri Dec 13 16:03:04 2013] [error] [client 176.26.50.20] File does not exist: /etc/zpanel/panel/etc/styles/zpanelx/css/style.css, referer: http://api.pingrglobe.com/?mode=getServers&apiCode=cb8844
[Fri Dec 13 16:05:53 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Dec 13 16:06:46 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:06:46 2013] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Fri Dec 13 16:06:46 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Dec 13 16:06:46 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Dec 13 16:06:46 2013] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Fri Dec 13 16:06:46 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 13 16:10:02 2013] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
[Fri Dec 13 16:10:02 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Dec 13 16:10:02 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Dec 13 16:10:02 2013] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Fri Dec 13 16:10:02 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 13 16:29:49 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Dec 13 16:29:50 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:29:50 2013] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Fri Dec 13 16:29:50 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Dec 13 16:29:50 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Dec 13 16:29:50 2013] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Fri Dec 13 16:29:50 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 13 16:36:23 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Dec 13 16:38:38 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:38:42 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:39:01 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:39:17 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:41:32 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:43:14 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:43:38 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:47:17 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:47:29 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:48:04 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:48:16 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:49:17 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:49:36 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:49:39 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:50:40 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:50:42 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:54:19 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:54:22 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:54:35 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:54:38 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:58:19 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:58:46 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 16:59:28 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 17:01:04 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 17:01:05 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 17:01:06 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 17:01:06 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 13 17:01:07 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
```

Comment: It's not possible for us to diagnose this for you as you haven't provided any useful information. What do you logs say ?

Comment: I will update my post within a minute with log info. :)

Comment: Updated for ya!

Comment: Regarding your first error, can you check /etc/hosts for "xx.xx.xx.xx ctrl.lesamportfolio.com" ? where xx is an ip address

Comment: It's 127.0.0.1 ctrl.lesamportfolio.com

Comment: that is the problem, put a real ip, not localhost (127.0.0.1). The private or public ip of your server

Comment: Still not starting, no errors either when I type the command.

Comment: Is SELinux enabled? Do you get any useful output if you `ausearch -m avc -ts today | audit2allow`? If the answer to both questions is yes, you need to fix the labeling on those files.

Comment: [root@database ~]# ausearch -m avc -ts today | audit2allow
-bash: audit2allow: command not found
<no matches>

Comment: Could you limit the log posting to what's relevant to your latest attempts at starting Apache?  You've got a week's worth of entries there, and a good chunk of it no doubt relates to problems you've already solved.

Comment: Confirm the paths in your Apache configurations - do they exist ? Re-build the configurations if possible. Could you provide a snippet of your configurations ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of your initial error using the [ServerName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername) directive in your apache config file, like so:

`ServerName fqdn.domain.com`

However, this is usually just a warning message, and shouldn't actually prevent Apache from starting.  Can you your httpd.conf?  Or the output of `apachectl configtest`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have multiple errors.  One that I see is that you are not allowed to execute php from apache ? Have you check that those scripts have executable permissions for the user that apache is running as?